# Tesorflow: matrix initialize

Tags: matrix, tensorflow

I get a matrix **A** with the shape **[ M** x **N** x **L1 ]** and another matrix B with shape **[ M** x **L2 ]**, **L1** and **L2** have the same dimension size but with different values. The M in A and B are corresponding.

For every dimension in **A[M,:,:]**, I want to give them the value **B[M:]**. That's to say, I want use **L2** in matrix **B[M]** to initialize every **L1** in **A[M,:]**, how can I operate this in tensorflow?

**Details**: Suppose **A** is a matrix that contains **M** sentences with **N** words that have **L1** dimension word embeddings. **B** is a matrix contains **M** sentences with a score in **L2** dimension. len(**L1**)=len(**L2**).

How can I replace every word embedding in the sentence with the score in matrix **B**?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You just want to know how to initialize A from B in tensorflow?

Comment: Actually ,I want to know how to transfer the value in the third dim of **A** to the value in the second dim of **B**.  **A** and **B** are tensors in tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

I figured out today morning.
One possible way is:

As M&N are None dim in tensorflow, **A: [None, None, L], B: [None, L]**, so I used tf.transpose()

what we should do is :

**1, swift dimensions:**

tf.transpose(**A,[1,0,2]**): **[ M x N x L1 ]  ===>  [ N x M x L1 ]**

```
                        A      ------>   A_
```

**2,initialize all the A_ matrix with 1 value** 
change the values to 1:

```
                        A_ ====> _A_
```

**3, mul the matrixs:**

```
                       tf.mul(_A_, B)     ===>   C
```

**4,Then swift back the dim**:

```
                       tf.transpose(**C, [1,0,2]**)
```